# remove last null value in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative

This is array, i have to remove only last empty value only last of array **like rtrim**.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 50967
        [2] => 50647
        [3] => 4024
        [4] => 
        [5] => testme
        [6] => 125
        [7] => onlinecode.org
        [8] => 
        [9] => You
        [10] => 4
        [11] => Toys
        [12] => 135
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
        [15] => 
    )
```

i'm use this code :

```
print_r(array_filter($arr, 'strlen'));
```

but its remove all null value of array.

expected output :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 50967
        [2] => 50647
        [3] => 4024
        [4] => 
        [5] => testme
        [6] => 125
        [7] => onlinecode.org
        [8] => 
        [9] => You
        [10] => 4
        [11] => Toys
        [12] => 135
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $arr is 2-dimensional array (not clearly showed in the OP), this will remove the last member of each sub-array if empty:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if (trim($val[count($val) - 1]) == '') {
        unset($val[count($val) - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @krunal Normal, since it addressed what was showed by your OP: a 1-dim array! See my updated answer for a 2-dim array.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you want:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;
$d = 4;

$arr = array(
array ( $b, $d, $c, $a, $b),
array ($c, $a),
array ( $b, $d,  $c ),
array( $c, $d, $a, $b, $b)
);
echo "before:\n";
print_r($arr);

foreach($arr as $k1=>$q) {
  foreach($q as $k2=>$r) {
    if($r == $c) {
      unset($arr[$k1][$k2]);
    }
  }
}
echo "after:\n";
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Output:

```
before:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
        )

)
after:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
        )

)
```

As you can see, all the 3's have gone...

Answer (score 0):

You can test the last array item and if it's empty, remove it.

**edit** added support for multi-dimension of OP's `$arr`

```
$found_value = 0;
foreach ($arr as &$array) {
    do {
        if (empty(($array[count($array)-1]))) {
            array_pop($array);
        } else {
            $found_value = 1;
        }
    } while (empty($found_value));
}
```

here is the **updated** [pastebin showing it works](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f7c9705e61cfde87868c6ceb8e67859b24be8f47)

Comment: thank for answer, but i want to remove all last null value not one.

Comment: @krunal - ah, no worries, a trivial update.  pastebin also updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to solve your problem.
You can do it like this:

```
// Let Array be
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6, null, null];

foreach (array_reverse($arr) as $value) {
    if(is_null($value)) {
        unset($arr[count($arr) - 1]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
print_r($arr);

/* Output
array:7 [
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
  2 => 3
  3 => 4
  4 => null
  5 => 6
] */
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use a delimiter to convert the Array to string. then trim the last delimitets. finally trans back.

```
<?php

$multiArray = [ 
                [1,2,3,4,null,6,null,null],
                [2,3,4,5,null, 8, null, 8, null, null]
              ];

var_dump(array_map("mytrim", $multiArray));


function mytrim($array)
{
  return explode(',', rtrim( implode(',', $array), ','));
}
```

then output:

```
kris-roofe@krisroofe-Rev-station:~$ php cal.php 
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(1) "8"
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
    [7]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

Comment: i have multidimensional-array.

Comment: @krunal check it, I make it for multiarray.